# Are the Rpi CPUs fabbed specifically for Raspberry Pi Foundation, or are they "off the shelf" components?

Tags: cpu, official-foundation

I'm curious if these are identical parts to those found in other electronic devices, or if they are fabbed specifically for the Rpi. Most interested in the latest 3 and 4s, but the history of it would also be welcome.

Comment: Probably of interest: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/egwo6z/was_the_broadcom_bcm2711_designed_specifically/

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for that. It does answer my question. Got into a discussion about this with someone, was hoping to clarify it for both our sakes.